# Can I order venue result by "Here now" field in Foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare

I`m using search method of Foursquare API.
I`d like to order the venue result by field "herenow"
Is it possible?

I`m using this method of API:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get Foursquare to return to you pre-ordered, but you can always sort it after you get the data.